# filtering out repeats

Tags: php

I'm creating a program which goes through data in a array and filter outs any repeats within it and then echos out anything which isn't a repeated piece of data

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($urlArray); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($urlArray); $j++) {
                if($i != $j)
                {
                    if($urlArray[$i] !== $urlArray[$j])
                    echo $urlArray[$i];
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm fairly certain there's something wrong but I can't quite spot it, any help with this would be great.

Comment: What makes you think there is something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont get, how your array is structured, but whats about just `array_unique()`

```
$urlArray = array_unique($urlArray);
```

Or in your case (because you want to `echo` it

```
foreach (array_unique($urlArray) as $url) echo $url;
```

Update:
Sorry, just mixed up two functions :) Of course its `array_unique()` and not `array_filter()`.

Comment: You sir are brilliant, didn't even know that function existed

Answer (score 0):

You could use built in function [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicate values in array

```
$result = array_unique($urlArray);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: If you want to test against static values, never use the function call in the test expression. Its called in every iteration cycle.